# Angular Form Validator input assigned but return error

Tags: angular, forms, validation, input, mat-form-field

In my sing-up component i create a form-group for the validation of the input field.

```
this.UserForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  surname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  username: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$')
  ])),
  etc...
})
```

so i have the input with its control

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
  <input #name matInput type="text" [value]="userData.name" formControlName="name"
        (change)="onChangeName(name.value)" required>
  <mat-error *ngFor="let validation of account_validation_messages.name">
        <mat-error class="error-message" 
            *ngIf="newUserForm.get('nameUser').hasError(validation.type)
             && (newUserForm.get('nameUser').dirty || newUserForm.get('nameUser').touched)">
                    {{validation.message}}</mat-error>
         </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field>
```

and it works... but... if i use the same componet for the user update it fills the input with

```
[value]="userData.name"
```

and if i "touche" it... it gives me error like it was empty... but it isn't...

How can i fix this error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `newUserForm.get('nameUser').setValue( … )` instead of `[value]="…"` when using reactive forms.

Comment: tnx... i supposed it was something like this, but never thinked obout it... tnk u so much :)